# Checar se arquivo existe em tempo de execução

Tags: php, while

Preciso verificar se um arquivo foi deletado enquanto executo uma determinada função.

No início da execução o resultado de `is_file` é `true`, porém durante a execução o arquivo será deletado e, essa é a condicional para seguir com código: o arquivo não existir mais.

Como posso fazer?

Abaixo o código:

```
<?php

$raiz = dirname(__FILE__);
$teste = is_file($raiz.'/teste.pid');

while($teste == true){
    $teste = is_file($raiz . '/teste.pid');
    if ($teste == false) {
        continue;
    }
}
echo " --- continua execução --- <br>";
```

Comment: Sabe o que o `continue` faz?

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, seu código está redundante. Pois:

```
while ($teste == true) {
    $teste = is_file($raiz . '/teste.pid');
    if ($teste == false) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

É o mesmo que:

```
while ($teste == true) {
    $teste = is_file($raiz . '/teste.pid');
}
```

Pois se o teste for false a execução sai do laço. E você está usando o `continue` errado, o continue diz ao interpretador "Esse ciclo já foi, pode ir para o próximo" ignorando o restante do código **dentro do laço** desta iteração e partindo para a próxima.
Ou seja, o seu `continue` faria mais sentido sendo um `break` pois se a condição do if for verdadeira a execução sai do laço. Porém se a condição do `if` é igual a condição do `while`, então não faz sentido a existência deste `if`.

Dito isso, seu `while` ainda poderia ser apenas:

```
while (is_file($raiz . '/teste.pid'));
```

---

Mas vamos para o quê acredito ser o motivo do seu código não estar funcionando:

Penso que podem ser o seguinte:

A função [`is_file`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-file.php) do PHP faz uso de cache para diminuir operações de I/O por motivos de performance. Conforme documentação:

> Nota: Os resultados desta função são cacheados. Veja [`clearstatcache()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.clearstatcache.php) para mais detalhes.

Então para resolver isso você teria invalidar a cache e tentar novamente. Talvez não seja a melhor solução, afinal este cache existe por um motivo, mas eu usaria em conjunto com a função [`sleep()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sleep.php) para pausar o script e esperar o arquivo ser excluído.

Um exemplo:

```
<?php
$raiz = dirname(__FILE__);

while (is_file($raiz . '/teste.pid')) {
    sleep(1);
    clearstatcache();
}

echo " --- continua execução --- <br>";
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o file_exists:

```
$filename = '/caminho/para/arquivo.txt';

$teste = file_exists($filename)
```

E sair da função utilizando `break`

```
if (!$teste) {
    break;
}
```

Segue links para estudo:

[break](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.break.php)

[file_exists](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php)